# How to specify several string options for an argument in Python Type Hinting

Tags: python, type-hinting

I want to set up only a limited range of options for an argument in a method of Python. For example, how can I write it so the kind argument can only set to 'image' and 'video'

```
def get_all_creatives_from_accounts(self, 
                                    accounts = None,
                                    kind: Union['image', 'video'] = "video",
                                    limit_per_page=100) -> pd.DataFrame)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal):

```
from typing import Union, Literal

def get_all_creatives_from_accounts(self, accounts=None,
    kind: Literal["image", "video"] = "video",
    limit_per_page=100) -> pd.DataFrame):
```